# Papaparse output without comma (multiple records)

Tags: javascript, papaparse

I have CSV that is parsed with Papaparse and the output is the following:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "Test1"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "Test2"
    }
]
```

And I need to receive the following instead:

```
[ //also could be without this
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "Test1"
    } //without the comma
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "Test2"
    }
] //also could be without this
```

Is there a way to directly remove that comma that separates two records with Papaparse or do I have to do it through code?

Thanks.

Comment: It wouldn't be valid Javascript/JSON without the comma. Not sure why you would need to do this. What are you trying to do? Perhaps, there is a better solution.

Comment: You are right, this is because COPY command for Redshift is expecting that format: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html

When I pass a regular JSON with only one record, it works... but when I try to do it with multiple records, it breaks.